# How do I determine which URLLoader failed programmatically?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, error-handling

I'm developing a flash application that is getting information from a remote server using a URLLoader.  I have a function that will create a request for information based on the product ID. When there is an error, I want to fall back to an alternate URL, but to create the alternate URL, I need to know the product ID.  What is the best method to determine which URLLoader failed (and which product request failed) so that I can regenerate the new URL?

My functions are below:

```
function loadData(productID:String):URLLoader {
  var productURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("/path/to/product/" + productID);
  var dataLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

  dataLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parseData);
  dataLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleDataError);
  dataLoader.load(productURL);

  return dataLoader;
}

function handleDataError(e:IOErrorEvent) {
  var productID:String = ???;
  var altProductURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("/alternate/path/to/product/" + productID);
  var dataLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

  dataLoader.load(altProductURL);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap your error handler in a local variable (which describes a new function) so you can pass the ID to the method which receives the error event:

```
function loadData(productID:String):URLLoader {
  var productURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("/path/to/product/" + productID);
  var dataLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

  var errHandler:Function = function(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
    handleDataError(event, productID);
  };

  dataLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parseData);
  dataLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errHandler);
  dataLoader.load(productURL);

  return dataLoader;
}

function handleDataError(e:IOErrorEvent, productID:String) {
  var altProductURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("/alternate/path/to/product/" + productID);
  var dataLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

  dataLoader.load(altProductURL);
}
```

Comment: Picked this one because it is really simple and answers the question elegantly and with minimal amounts of code.  If I needed to use this long term or if I was going to use it in more than one place (such as across different projects) I would probably use Juan's solution, though.

Comment: @Steropes, glad it worked out. I agree though - Juan's solution is quite elegant and nicely hides the failover functionality.

Answer (score 7):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't `e.target` or `e.currentTarget` **be** the URLLoader that failed?

Comment: Yes. In your handleDataError function, "e.currentTarget" will evaluate to the loader instance. From there, one option you have is simply to access the url that you used and reverse engineer the ID?

Comment: Yes, the e.target and e.currentTarget gets the URLLoader that failed, but it doesn't have a url attribute that will give me any information to determine which URLLoader it is.  I'm looking for the best way to cross reference that URLLoader object with other data, namely a productID. In other words, how do I tie the URLLoader object to the productID in such a way to get the productID from an unnamed URLLoader object?

Comment: @Myk: URLLoader in this case does not have a url property (unless I have a bug somewhere).

Comment: you had asked for the [URLLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html), and I hadn't thought about the fact that the [URLRequest](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) was what stored the `url`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to wrapping the error handler in a closure or retrieving the id from the target would be writting a custom loader that hides the retry mechanism, so your could use it pretty much like if it were a normal loader.

Something like this (I just wrote this in notepad, so it probably has errors, but just to give you the idea...):

```
public class ProductDataLoader extends EventDispatcher {

    private var _paths:Array;
    private var _id:String;
    private var _state:int; 

    private var _loader:URLLoader;
    private var _data:Object;

    public function get data():Object {
        return _data;
    }

    public function ProductDataLoader(id:String) {
        _paths = [
            "/path/to/product/",
            "/alternate/path/to/product/"
        ];
        _id = id;
        _state = -1;

        _loader = new URLLoader();
        _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);
        _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleError);   

    }

    public function load():void {
        if(hasNextPath()) {
            _loader.load(new URLRequest(getNextPath()));
        } else {
            //  here, we ran out of paths to try
            //  you shouldn't get here unless you call loadProduct() 
                    //      more than once. 
            //  you should probably throw an error here, but that's up to
        }

    }

    private function hasNextPath():Boolean {
        return _state < _paths.length - 1;
    }

    private function getNextPath():String {
        _state++;
        return _paths[_state] + _id;    
    }

    private function handleComplete(e:Event):void {
        // redispatch the complete event
        _data = _loader.data;
        dispatchEvent(e);
    }

    private function handleError(e:Event):void {
        if(hasNextPath()) {
            loadProduct();
        } else {
            //  we tried all paths without success
            //  so we just redispatch the error event
            dispatchEvent(e);
        }   
    }

}
```

Then in your load function:

```
function loadData(productID:String):URLLoader {

    var productLoader:ProductDataLoader = new ProductDataLoader(productId);
    dataLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parseData);
    dataLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleDataError);
    dataLoader.load();
}
```

Comment: @bedwyr. Thanks. What I like about this approach is that it hides the mechanism from the caller, so the calling code stays simple. Also, if you want to add some more robust error handling (like making sure your loader stays in a consistent state, it's not re-entered while it's loading, etc), you can do it easily without cluttering the "client" code, which can treat this loader almost as a regular loader.

Comment: Though more complex than bedwyr's code, this solution is more robust and would allow me to future-proof my application and easily allow me to reuse the code if needed.  I picked bedwyr's solution over this one only because I needed a simple solution that would only be used once and I chose code legibility over robustness.